# Microsoft Teams Incoming Webhook Button \w File-Link

Tags: python, json, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I'm sending a message to a Microsoft Teams channel using incoming webhooks. This works perfectly fine except for the button "Open log" which should open a file via the browser but simply doesn't.

JSON

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "themeColor": "0076D7",
    "summary": "Error Log",
    "sections": [{
        "activityTitle": "Error in integration " + integration_name,
        "activitySubtitle": "live stage",
        "markdown": True,
        "text": message
    }],
    "potentialAction": [{
        "@type": "ActionCard",
        "name": "Open log",
        "actions": [{
            "@type": "OpenUri",
            "name": "Open log",
            "targets": [{
                "os": "default",
                "uri": "file://someserver/d$/somefolder/logs/" + logname
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

The result of this webhook call looks like this:
[Message via webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMsNJ.png)

My problem is, that this button does absolutely nothing. If I use standard websites, even android/iOS URLs, it works like expected.

Any help to solve this is much appreciated! Am I doing something wrong? Is Microsoft Teams blocking file:// links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, currently we sanitize (block) file:// links as they are a pretty significant security hole (e.g. local executables/batch files). See [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/browsersec/wikis/Part2.wiki#URL_scheme_access_rules) for more info.

That said, your use case seems both valid and safe. How would you like it to work while still being secure?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I suppose, the security aspect overweighs the "nice-to-have feature". Would it be possible to have a setting in Teams for such features (e.g. allow per channel and filetype)? Is there any other way to post file links from within my own network (without browser, just \\servername\d$\folder\file.txt)?

Comment: I'd also like to be able to use a webhook to post a link to an internal file, like \\servername\dir\file.txt . Is this possible?

Comment: Could something like this work if the target uri was something like 'myfile://foobar.txt' where you have your own hanlder registered to the URI scheme 'myfile'? Or are all links blocked other than http or https?

Answer (score 0):

Is there really no way to create a webhook message containing a link pointing to an file like file://myshare/file.htm?
We posting messages with a webhook and we also want to be able to post links to stuff in our companies intranet.